# Finding out the name to `:require` in a namespace

Tags: clojure, package, leiningen

I am following this tutorial: https://practicalli.github.io/blog/posts/web-scraping-with-clojure-hacking-hacker-news/ and I have had a hard time dealing with the `:require` part of the `ns` macro. This tutorial shows how to parse HTML and pull out information from it with a library called enlive, and to use it, I first had to put

```clj
   ...
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
                 [enlive "1.1.6"]]
   ...
```

in my `project.clj`, and require the library in `core.clj` as the following:

```clj
(ns myproject.core
  (:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])
  (:gen-class))
```

I spent so much time finding out the name `net.cgrand.enlive-html`, since it was different from the package's name itself (which is just `enlive`), and I couldn't find it through any of the `lein` commands (I eventually found it out by googling).

How can I easily find out what name to `require`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Practical approach

If your editor/IDE helps with auto-completion and
docs, that might be a first route.

Other than that, libraries usually have some read-me online, where they show off
what they do (what to require, how to use that).

#### Strict approach

If you really have nothing about a library, you will find the downloaded
library in you `~/.m2/repository` directory.  Note that deps without the naming
convention of "group/artifact" will just double on the artifact name, Next is
the version.  So you can find your libraries JAR file here:
`.m2/repository/enlive/enlive/1.1.6/enlive-1.1.6.jar`.

JAR files are just ZIP-Files.  Inside the JAR file you will usually find the
source files of the library.  The directory structure reflects the package
structure.  E.g. one file there is `net/cgrand/enlive_html.clj` (note the use
of the `_` instead of `-`, this is due to name munging for the JVM).  You then
can require the file in your REPL and explore with `doc` or `dir` etc.  Or you
open this file, to see the docs and source code in one chunk.

Comment: +1 for the README.  Find the library on clojars.org or search.maven.org.  Follow the link to the library's Github project.  The README will be front and center.  And, +(three gold stars) for unzipping and cruising through the source code, or even clicking through it on Github.  Lots of Clojure libraries are surprisingly brief.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I get this from the documentation / tutorial for the library.

https://github.com/cgrand/enlive Check out the Quick Tutorial, which starts with the needed require.